# Access Application context data through activities

Tags: java, android, geolocation, android-location

This question can be a little complex, but I try to explain it as best I can.

Basically I am trying to get last location (lat, long) with my application, so I did something like this:

```
public class GoogleLocation extends Activity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = null;
Location mLastLocation = null;
LocationManager lm;
Double latitude;
Double longitude;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    connectLocation();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                    30);
        }
    }
        Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if(location != null){
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }
        Log.d("IMHERE","IMHERE");
        Log.d("latitude",String.valueOf(latitude));

        final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                //Log.d("latitudee",String.valueOf(latitude));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

            }
        };

        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 10, locationListener);


    }


protected void onStart() {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    super.onStart();
}

protected void onStop() {
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

public void connectLocation(){
    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);

        //**************************
        builder.setAlwaysShow(true); //this is the key ingredient
        //**************************

        PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
                LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, builder.build());
        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
                final Status status = result.getStatus();
                final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
                switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                        // a dialog.
                        try {
                            // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                            // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                            status.startResolutionForResult(
                                    GoogleLocation.this, 1000);
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                            // Ignore the error.
                        }
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                        // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mLastLocation = location;
    Log.d("mLastLocation",String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}
}
```

It just works if it pass trough the onLocationChanged, so the first time it enters it takes some seconds to get the location, the second time I try that, my application already got a last location and it takes more 10 seconds to reach the new location.

At this point everything fine.

Now what I want to do is run this in background, thats why I changed the extends to activity, and try in background with that onLocationChanged to updated my location.

Something like in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28546461/how-to-run-locationlistener-in-background).

Every time my application detects a new location, I want to updated(do a setLocation or whatever in my class).

As I said I want to do this every time I start my application and this should run that in background, every time I access this class it should retrieve me the last location, and I want to access this class from different locations.

**My full code:**

```
public class GoogleLocation extends Activity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = null;
Location mLastLocation = null;
LocationManager lm;
Double latitude;
Double longitude;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    connectLocation();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                    30);
        }
    }
        Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if(location != null){
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }
        Log.d("IMHERE","IMHERE");
        Log.d("latitude",String.valueOf(latitude));

        final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                //Log.d("latitudee",String.valueOf(latitude));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

            }
        };

        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 10, locationListener);


    }


protected void onStart() {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    super.onStart();
}

protected void onStop() {
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

public void connectLocation(){
    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);

        //**************************
        builder.setAlwaysShow(true); //this is the key ingredient
        //**************************

        PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
                LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, builder.build());
        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
                final Status status = result.getStatus();
                final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
                switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                        // a dialog.
                        try {
                            // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                            // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                            status.startResolutionForResult(
                                    GoogleLocation.this, 1000);
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                            // Ignore the error.
                        }
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                        // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mLastLocation = location;
    Log.d("mLastLocation",String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: So you basically want to keep getting location in the background and update the UI everytime you get a new location ?

Comment: don't need to update the UI, just need to get the last location, in the background he does the job with a timer to get updated locations, and when want to get a location from a activity i want to get the last, so i can send this to the server, the UI dont need to updated

Comment: I'm noticing a trend with confusion on `getLastKnownLocation`. Are you learning this from a tutorial online, an online class, or some other resource? If so, can you share that resource?

Comment: i learned with all resources i found on the internet :S, i spend two days on this

Comment: basicly as i learned, the onlocationchanged provides me a value, but that value takes a time, if i try to get the lastknownlocation without the locationchanged my aplication doesn't track changes and the value will be always null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FULL CODE**:

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;

import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;

import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.media.Image;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.RoundedBitmapDrawable;
import android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsStates;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsStatusCodes;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

import static android.location.Criteria.POWER_HIGH;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements  GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult> ,LocationListener {


    Double lat, lng;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent k = getIntent();

        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
        } else {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }

    }




    protected LocationRequest createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        return mLocationRequest;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Log.e("Connection", "GOOGLE API Connected");


        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(createLocationRequest());
        PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
                LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient,
                        builder.build());
        result.setResultCallback(this);

    }

    protected void getPhoneLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

        Log.e("Connection","GOOGLE API Suspended");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

        Log.e("Connection","GOOGLE API Failed : " + connectionResult.toString() );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        super.onStart();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult locationSettingsResult) {

        final Status status = locationSettingsResult.getStatus();

        switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                if (!(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) ==
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) ==
                                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {

                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                            222);
                }
                else
                {
                    getPhoneLocation();
                }
                // All location settings are satisfied. The client can
                // initialize location requests here.
                break;
            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                // Location settings are not satisfied, but this can be fixed
                // by showing the user a dialog.
                try {
                    // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                    // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                    status.startResolutionForResult(
                            MainActivity.this,
                            111);
                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                    // Ignore the error.
                }
                break;
            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way
                // to fix the settings so we won't show the dialog.
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.e("Activity","Result");
        if(requestCode != 333) {
            if (!(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) ==
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) ==
                            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                        222);
            } else {
                getPhoneLocation();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        if(requestCode == 222) {
            if (grantResults.length != 0) {
                getPhoneLocation();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        lat = location.getLatitude();
        lng = location.getLongitude();
        }
    } `
```

This code gets you location between 10 - 5 second intervals and they pass through onLocationChanged ... the GetLastKnowLocation gets you the last known location to the device... so sometimes it could return null...

**CODE EXPLANATION**
This code block in the OnCreate connects to the Google API Client with callbacks pointing back to the activity.

```
if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
        } else {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
```

**THIS IS IMPORTANT**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements  GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult> ,LocationListener {
```

**Creates A location request like yours with intervals**

```
protected LocationRequest createLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    return mLocationRequest;
}
```

**WHEN GOOGLE API CONNECTS CHECK SETTINGS AND PERMISSIONS**

```
 @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Log.e("Connection", "GOOGLE API Connected");


    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
            .addLocationRequest(createLocationRequest());
    PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
            LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient,
                    builder.build());
    result.setResultCallback(this);

}
```

**THE SETTINGS CALLBACK RETURNS TO ACTIVITY HERE**
In this block we check the status of the settings and see if they return success we check for permission ... if we have permission to access the location ... then we getPhoneLocation() **OPTION A** ... if we dont have permission we ask for permission and the callback goes to **OPTION B**

```
`@Override`
    public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult locationSettingsResult) {

    final Status status = locationSettingsResult.getStatus();

    switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
            if (!(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) ==
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) ==
                            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                        222);
            }
            else
            {
                getPhoneLocation();
            }
            // All location settings are satisfied. The client can
            // initialize location requests here.
            break;
        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
            // Location settings are not satisfied, but this can be fixed
            // by showing the user a dialog.
            try {
                // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                status.startResolutionForResult(
                        MainActivity.this,
                        111);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                // Ignore the error.
            }
            break;
        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
            // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way
            // to fix the settings so we won't show the dialog.
            break;
    }
}
```

**OPTION B** 
In this block we get the Return from checking the user permission ... if he accepted the request for location we go on to get the PhoneLocation ... if no we close the activity.

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.e("Activity","Result");
        if(requestCode != 333) {
            if (!(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) ==
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) ==
                            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                        222);
            } else {
                getPhoneLocation();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
```

**ADD THE LOCATION REQUESTS** (**OPTION A**)

```
protected void getPhoneLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

    }
```

**NOW YOU HAVE LOCATION**
Now you have the location in the given interval as long as the Activity is open.

```
 @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        lat = location.getLatitude();
        lng = location.getLongitude();
        }
```

Comment: didn't test yet will test tomorrow, you said as long the activity is open, i need that to run on background not in activity :S

Comment: To make it run in the background you need to make a Service check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28535885/3722165

Comment: yeah i saw that answer but i couldn't know how to get the location